# How to Quit by default X11 when shutting down

Tags: force-quit

When I shutdown my computer I am having followin pop-up for `X11`, by default I want to always `Quit` instead of manually clicking.

[image]

**[Q]** How to accept by defualt Quit for `X11` when it is closed?

Comment: If you close all the apps running in X11 then the dialog box does not appear when you quit the application.

Comment: I do not run any app in X11, just allowing copy string over ssh connection. I also closed all the running terminals before that

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1448251/disable-message-do-you-really-want-to-quit-x11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to the X11 preferences removes the popup-

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 no_quit_alert true
```

Comment: Should I run this single time in terminal or add into `.bashrc`?

Comment: Just add the key once.