# XQuartz right away quits itself

Tags: x11, xquartz

macOS Catalina Version 10.15.5

I have downloaded XQuartz from following page (https://www.xquartz.org/). The application installed and shown on the `Utilities` folder. When I open it, it is shown a second on the docker and always gone away (quits itself). It does not show up on the running applications, so I crashes due to some reason.

[image]

I don't know how can I fix this issue, since I am not able to open the application. Is there any way can I fix this issue?

Comment: What has changed on your system since https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395682/how-to-quit-by-default-x11-when-shutting-down (there it seemed to have worked)?

Comment: Actually it was working yesterday and nothing is changed. I think I have clicked `Hide` for XQuartz on the Dock bar and hide option did not show up again. After multiple reboots XQuartz shows up on the Dock. I am not sure could it be the reason? @nohillside

Comment: Hard to say what went wrong afterwards...

Comment: I cannot find its log files. Since the app does not open I cannot access its preferences. When I open it it shows up on the `Force Quit Applications` but removed also after a second. Maybe if I can start it from terminal (without a gui) I can find some clues

Comment: `/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin` seems like this open the program but it dos not open within Dock or finder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by running from the Terminal.

```
run_Xquartz() {
  [ $(ps aux | grep -E '[X]quartz' | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && echo 'Xquartz is already running' \
  || nohup /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11.bin > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}

$ run_Xquartz
```

- If `Xquartz` is already running on the background it prints `Xquartz is already running`.
- If `Xquartz` is not running on the background it runs it on the background using `nohup`.

=> When `Xquartz` starts running on the dock you will see it.